# Filter values from Arrays in Json (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js, filter

So I have loaded a JSON object from D3 and now want to filter out some columns from the array. My only problem is that doing:

```
Object.attribute;
```

doesn't return what I want. The structure of my JSON object is as follows. It holds 1000 objects and each array hold attributes inside of it. I am getting my data from https://data.raleighnc.gov/resource/xce4-kemu.json, for reference.

If I do

```
Object[0].attribute;
```

It returns the actual value of the object, so like "12". Where as I want it to return all the values where that key is present

In the URL you can see an example of the JSON. I want to, for example return a JSON where only the issueddate_mth, statelicnum, and constcompletedofficial attributes are present.

An Snippet of what I tried is:

```
 var raleigh_data = "https://data.raleighnc.gov/resource/xce4-kemu.json";
d3.json(raleigh_data, function(error, data) {
var filtered_data = data.filter(function(d,i,e) {
return d.issueddate_mth;
});
```

}

Comment: it's an array of 1000 objects, not 1000 arrays

Comment: what do you want to filter from that data?

Comment: use something like `var filteredArray = xxx.filter(callbackFunction)` to filter an array (the array in this case is a var called xxx ... you **dont** want to use a var called `Object`) ... callbackFunction is a function that accepts 3 arguments, the item, the index and the whole array ... do your logic and return true or false to include/exclude the item in the new array returned

Comment: So am I understanding correctly-- you want to iterate over every object in the array and return an array of all values for  a given property present in each object?

Comment: @anied I updated my answer to hopefully make it more clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var data = [your array of 1000 objects]
var filteredData = [];
data.forEach(function(item) { 
    if (item.issueddate_mth && item.statelicnum && item.constcompletedofficial) {
        filteredData.push(item);
    }
});
```

This will get you an array that only contains items from your original array with the specified properties.

Also, I am not 100% sure if you only want those three properities. If so, you could easily just push `{ issueddate_mth: item.issueddate_mth, statelicnum: item.statelicnum, constcompletedofficial: item.constcompletedofficial }` instead of `item` in the `forEach` callback

Comment: Is there a way to do the reverse. Meaning that I take out properties that I don't want in the the JSON Object?

Comment: Ok I tried the second part as you specified and it worked like a charm. Thank you!!